# Get Hint attribute Value from AttributeSet

Tags: android, view, attributes, android-edittext

i have overridden EditText as given in **[this link](http://arunbadole1209.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/how-to-create-edittext-with-crossx-button-at-end-of-it/)**.

Now while declaring this field inside layout i am using

```
<com.and.ab1209.ClearableEditText
android:id=”@+id/edit_text_clearable”
android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
android:hint="My Hint Goes here"
android:layout_height=”wrap_content” />
```

How do i retrieve this hint value inside any of these constructor.

```
 public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){...}
 public ClearableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){...}
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can access the standard xml attributes by doing the following inside your views constructor:

```
final String xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
//If you had a background attribute this is the resource id
int backgroundResource = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(xmlns, "background", -1);
//This is your views hint
String hint = attrs.getAttributeValue(xmlns, "hint");
```

It does not matter if your view inherits from TextView, if you designate a hint using `android:hint` it will be accessible in your custom view.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access to "android" attributes. You can use `getHint()` after calling `super()` constructor. 
If you want create you own attribute follow [this tutorial](http://blog.infidian.com/2008/05/02/android-tutorial-42-passing-custom-variables-via-xml-resource-files/).

Comment: As ClearableEditText extends RelativeLayout i don't have getHint() method available.

Comment: than you should create own attributes and use it

Comment: that is quite long process and more code which i don't want to follow that so only i asked for this thing.

Answer (score 1):

use `this.getHint()` inside your constructor

Comment: As ClearableEditText extends RelativeLayout i don't have getHint() method available.

Comment: oh, you must extend `EditText` instead

Comment: thats not possible as i will be using `RelativeLayout` as outer most `Layout`. if that was the case then why would i customize `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

You can use android-namespaced attributes, by defining it in your's attributes set. For example:

**attrs_custom_input_field.xml**

```xml
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomInputField">
        <attr name="android:hint" format="string" />
        <attr name="android:text" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**CustomInputField.kt**

```kotlin
class CustomInputField : ConstraintLayout {
    // ....

    // init called from all constructors
    private fun init(attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) {
        val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs, R.styleable.CustomInputField, defStyle, 0)

        val hint = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomInputField_android_hint)
        val text = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomInputField_android_text)

        a.recycle()

        // use hint and text as you want
    }
}
```

You should define only existing attributes, otherwise, you will receive errors in the editor